# Android : How to analyze the trace files programmatically?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-testing, android-traceview

I have a list of trace files and I need to analyze them. Is there any way to analyze them programmatically without using the tool `traceview`?

Comment: But why don't you want to use traceview?

Comment: need to automate the job done by traceview

Answer (score 1):

The `dmtracedump` tool, used with the `-o` flag, will parse the file and dump it to stdout in a line-oriented human-readable format.  You can either parse this output or just clone the file parser from `dmtracedump`.  Sources [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/tools/dmtracedump/).